# Centering content inside header element

Tags: html, css

How do I center an img and an h1 in a div? 
Right now I have a png and an h1 in a header but the content is automatically in the top left. How do I put it in the middle and keep it responsive?
Here's my HTML:

```
   <header>
       <h1 id="title">Lorem Ipsum</h1>

       <img id="arrows" src="images/arrows.png">
       <h3 id="sub-title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
   </header>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just add `text-align: center` to the parent element. It is responsive as well.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="title">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <img id="arrows" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <h3 id="sub-title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I center it vertically?

Comment: You can try opening a new question since it changes the whole context of the answer and question as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the h1 and img in a div. From the div you can do margin: 0 auto; this will center h1 and img

```
div{ margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/3ystho4v/

```
header{text-align:center;position:relative}
header h3{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css

```
header {
  text-align: center;
}
```